# Delete file from sd card and change search icon and close button colour in Search view API 23

Tags: android, colors, icons, delete-file, android-sdcard

**1.** I tried deleting the files in sdcard, which is working before API 22.
Further I have added below permissions as well

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but still I'm unable to delete,
below is the code to delete the file, which is not working in API 23

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.delete_id:
            songsListData.remove(info.position);
            String path =  songsList.get(info.position).get("songPath");
            File filepath = new File(path);
            boolean deleted = filepath.delete();
            if(deleted)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**2.** I want to change the Search icon and close button colour to grey colour or if possible I want the replace with grey colour image, because I have set the search view background as black, due to this, icon and close buttons also shows in black colour.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Permissions 
1. Normal 
2. Dangerous

Normal permissions are automatically approved by Android while dangerous permissions need to be approved by Android users.

Before performing any operation which requires Dangerous permission, we need to check whether permission is Granted or Denied.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){
                        // check if WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission already available
                        if(checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            deleted =  deleteSong(deleteSongPath);
                        }else{
                            //WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE has not been granted

                            //Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
                            // and user would benefit from additonal context for the use of the permisiion.
                            if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                                Toast.makeText(this,"Storage Permission is needed to delete the slected song.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            // Request Stoarge Permission.
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
                        }
                    } else{
                        deleted =  deleteSong(deleteSongPath);
                    }
```

IF permission is granted we can proceed for the actual operation, else it'll show the dialog requesting the permission, to handle permission result, use below method.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_READ_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
                // get all songs from sdcard
                this.songsList = plm.getPlayList(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(this, "Storage Permission is needed to show the songs.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
                boolean deleted = false;
                deleted =  deleteSong(deleteSongPath);
                if(deleted) adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(this, "WRITE_STORAGE Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

You can include support library to your build.gradle file under app folder if you haven't already

```
dependencies {
// other stuff here
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1' 
// check if you have the latest version - if it's other than 22.1.1 then change it to that.

}
```